# Need a "SEE MORE" style Sidebar Menu in Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a side bar in which I need to display the dynamic availability of a category using PHP in side bar menu such that the menu must initially display say 3 categories and on clicking the "+" symbol it should display 5 more of the other categories along with the previous one again on clicking "+" other 5 categories should be displayed appended with the previous category list,

Please guide me if it is possible in Jquery

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please try it, and come back if you get stuck on any specific part, Stack Overflow won't write it for you.

Comment: @meager Please provide me the library..I dont need SO to write for me, just provide me the resource from where i can get it

Comment: What you're talking about isn't library-worthy. It's about 10 lines of jQuery and an AJAX call. There is no pre-built drop-in solution I can recommend.

Comment: @meager very obliged by your genuine directions but its My BAd, that I am newbie to Jquery, and I need this if you even have any example availabe with please provide me so...will be highly obliged

Comment: 76 word sentences with no punctuation are difficult to parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[jQuery Expander Plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/)

This may be helpful too

[Quick and Easy jQuery Read More Script Tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/5368/quick-and-easy-jquery-read-more-script-tutorial)

I found these on Google by searching for “jquery read more”

I’ve noticed that jQuery plugins are easy to find. Figuring out what they're *called* is harder.